# Find p that contains a function in $L^P((0,\infty))$

Tags: real-analysis

For $0<a<b<\infty$, define $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{a}+x^{b}} \quad ; x>0
$$

Find all $p \ge 1$ with $f \in L^p((0,\infty))$

I'm trying to solve the above problem as follows

$\int_{(0,\infty)}f^pd\mu= \int_{(0,\infty)}f^p(x)dx= lim_{c\rightarrow0} \int_c^d(\frac{1}{x^a+x^b})^pdx + lim_{e\rightarrow\infty}\int_d^e(\frac{1}{x^a+x^b})^pdx$  for some $e$.

I found it difficult to obtain $\int_c^d(\frac{1}{x^a+x^b})^pdx$; hence I cannot find p.

Would you please give me some hint to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $x>1$ then $x^b>x^a$, so $x^b+x^a>2x^a$, so $$\frac1{2x^a}<\frac1{x^a+x^b}<\frac1{x^a}\quad(x>1).$$ Similarly $$\frac1{2x^b}<\frac1{x^a+x^b}<\frac1{x^b}\quad(0<x<1).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would I ask one more question? I calculated $\int_{(0,\infty)} (\frac{1}{x^a})^p dx $ and obtained $\lim _{c \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1-ap}c^{1-ap}+\lim _{e \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1-ap}e^{1-ap}$. I think this values doesn't converge for whatever p values. Is my guess correct?

Comment: What you say about $\int_{(0,\infty)}\left(\frac1{x^a}\right)^p$ is correct, but as far as I can see it's irrelevant to the problem. The hint shows that all that matters is convergence of the two integrals $\int_{(1,\infty)}\left(\frac1{x^a}\right)^p$ and $\int_{(0,1)}\left(\frac1{x^b}\right)^p$

Comment: I understand what you say. I realized what I miss. I really appreciate it.